# How can i get application's installation path in Java?

Tags: java, windows, macos, path

I pack some executable files into the installer, I want to know how can I get application's installation path(Win/Mac).  Executable files are under the installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can get User working directory (pwd in linux) using this,

```
String workingDirectory = System.getProperties().getProperty("user.dir");
```

You can get the .jar file location using this,

```
URL jarLocation = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Comment: try this , https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-users-home-directory-system-property

Comment: Doesn't `"user.home"` return user’s home directory but not installation path?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the path into a String like so:

```
String workingDirectory = System.getProperties().getProperty("user.dir");
```

Or print it:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperties().getProperty("user.dir"));
```